# SQL Error 18456 state 8 on SharePoint Excel Services

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, excel-services, business-intelligence, ssas

I installed SQL Analysis Services. I want to test it via Excel Services on SharePoint.

I created new account with which I can easily login to SQL Server Management Studio: the username and password are demonstrably correct.

After that, I made a new Excel workbook and connected it with the database. I provided the account details created before and everything it works.

Then I tried to upload a workbook to the SharePoint Document Library. Upload is successful, but when i want to refresh the data there I get this error in the SQL log:

> "Login failed for user 'Darko'. Reason: Password did not match that
>   for the login provided."

What password is not matching? I can easily login to SQL Server Management Studio. I tried with the "sa" account but get the same result. I've set "SQL Server and Windows Authentication" in server properties. How do I fix or diagnose this issue?